# How can I select a specific user in the database and show only his info?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to build a table that contains user data from the database I've created.

Pretty much, I've sent an auto increment "ID" field in my users table, and now I want do a little multi choice box where all the users that are in the database are shown there. From there, I need them to be selectable.

However, I want the table that I have to show only the data from the user that was selected.

So let's say, for user with user name "John", I want to show on the table the following database fields:

> name
>
> route
>
> date
>
> bus_number

When selecting the user, I want all that information to show up on the table, but only his information.

Only thing I've tried so far was to display all the users data in the table so it contains all the names and respective fields.

I'm using this bootstrap table template as a testing resort.

```
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The function that grabs the user ID.

```
function getUserById($id){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=" . $id;
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $user;
}
```

I've tried doing a query by ID and limiting to 1, I did not get any output in the table after displaying the information on the table with php echo.

Comment: That query should work. If you are trying to echo out the `$user` variable, that won't work. Try something like `var_dump($user)` instead if you want to see what is in that variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem well, it seems to me that you need to do it like that:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
         <input name="userid[]" value="1" type="checkbox" />
        </th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
         <input name="userid[]" value="2" type="checkbox" />
        </th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
```

and then handle the $ids = $_POST['userid'] variable as an array. Change the function getUserById to function getUserById(array $ids)